# Salesforce.SE shouldn't have SQL as Tag

Tags: discussion

SOQL is NOT SQL. The tag is misleading and shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 11):

Marketing Cloud is a Salesforce product and uses SQL. Questions that relate to Marketing Cloud SQL are entirely on topic here.

The tag is not misleading in that context, but you are certainly encouraged to edit any post that incorrectly refers to SOQL as SQL.